# Ubuntu 18, proxy not working on terminal but work on browser

Tags: linux, proxy

(related and perhaps more simple  problem to solve: [proxy authentication by MSCHAPv2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161347/439867))

**Summary**: I am using a Ubuntu 18,  the proxy is working with web-browser **but not with terminal applications** (`wget`, `curl`  or `apt update`). **Any clues?** 
Seems the problem is [to interpretate a proxy's "PAC file"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file)... Is it? How to translate to Linux's proxy variables? 
... Or the problem is simple: my  proxy-config  (see step-by-step procedure below) was wrong?

---

**Details**:

By terminal `env | grep -i proxy` we obtain

```
https_proxy=http://user:pass@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
http_proxy=http://user:pass@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
ftp_proxy=http://user:pass@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080
```

and browser (Firefox) is working fine for any URL, but:

- `wget http://google.com` say 
   *Resolving pac._ProxyDomain_ (pac._ProxyDomain_)... etc.etc.0.26
   connecting to pac._ProxyDomain_ (pac._ProxyDomain_)|etc.etc.0.26|:80... conected.

  Proxy request has been sent, waiting for response ... 403 Forbidden 
  2019-07-25 12:52:19 ERROR 403: Forbidden.*
- `curl http://google.com` say 
  *"curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac"*

---

---

## Notes

(recent [news here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161264/439867): purge exported proxy changes something and not tested all again...)

The proxy configuration procedures that I used (there are some plug-and-play PAC file generator? I need a PAC file?)

### Config procedures used

1. All machine was running, with a direct non-proxy internet connection... Them the machine goes to the LAN with the proxy.
2. Add lines of "export *_proxy" (http, https and ftp) in my `~/.profile`. The URL definitions are in the form `http_proxy="http://user:pwd@etc"` 
   (supposing that is correct, because testesd before  with `user:pwd@http://pac.domain/proxy.pac` syntax and Firefox promped proxy-login)
   (if the current proxy-password is using `#` character, need to change?)
3. Add lines of "export *_proxy"  in my `~root/.profile`.
   (need it?)
4. (can reboot and test with `echo $http_proxy`)
5. [`visudo` procedure described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/19298/439867)
6. reboot and navigate by Firefox without need of login, direct (good is working!). Testing `env | grep -i proxy`, it shows all correct values as expected.
7. **Testing `wget` and `curl`** as the begin of this report, **proxy bug**.
8. Testing `sudo apt update`, bug.
9. ... after it  more one step, supponing that for `apt` not exist a file, created by `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy`  and add 3 lines for `Acquire::*::proxy "value";`  with value `http://user:pass@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080`. where pass is `etc%23etc`, url-encoded.

---

### Summary of tests performed

#### CONTEXT-1.1

(this was a problem but now ignoring it to focus on more relevant one)

After (the proxied) cable connection and  proxy configurations in the system. (see above section "Config procedures used"). Proxy-password with special character.

1. `curl http://google.com` say *"curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy..."*
   When change all `.profile` from `%23` to `#` the error on `wget` changes, but `curl` not.  Wget changes to 
   *"Error parsing proxy URL `http://user:pass@pac._ProxyDomain_/proxy.pac:8080`: Bad port number"*

PS: when used `$` on password the system (something in the internal `export http_proxy`  command or use of `http_proxy` confused it with a variable).

#### CONTEXT-1.2

Same as context-1.1 above, but password with no special character. Good and clean proxy-password.

1. `curl http://google.com` say *"curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy..."*

#### CONTEXT-2

After (the proxied) cable connection and no proxy configurations in the system (but confirmed that connection is working on browser after automatic popup form login).

1. `curl -x 192.168.0.1:8080 http://google.com`  *"curl: (7) Failed to connect..."*
2. `curl --verbose -x "http://user:pass@pac._proxyDomain_/proxy.pac" http://google.com` say *"curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy..."*

---

### Other configs in use

As @Roadowl suggested to check:

- files `~/.netrc` and `~root/.netrc` not exists
- file `more /etc/wgetrc` exists, but all commented, exept by  `passive_ftp = on`

Comment: Your browser may be using its own stored proxy settings. For instructions on creating a PAC file, look here: http://community.lightspeedsystems.com/courses/pac-files-explained/

Comment: Thanks @Roadowl (!), I will prepare it later (perhaps tomorow)... About automatic proxy-config for all my Linux,  [or `apt` to use a Proxy.pac file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/39616/439867), how to do it by terminal? (all instructions are by graphic but I need to test by terminal).

Comment: Maybe the proxy is set in `~/.netrc`?

Comment: You can call curl with the proxy set on the command-line, like so `curl -x .192.168.0.1:8080 http:/example.com/`; also see `man 1 curl`.

Comment: Also, this might be instructive: https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-proxies.html

Comment: And take a look at `/etc/wgetrc`.

Comment: There's a stray dot before the `192` in my earlier comment; omit that dot in your own trials.

Comment: Thanks @Roadowl. I edited the question text with answers on NOTES section.